# Ruby on Rails 3.1 without execjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

If you install Ruby on Rails 3.1 the gem [execjs](http://rubygems.org/gems/execjs) gets installed by default. I excluded [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), because I thought it needed execjs, but execjs wants to be installed anyway.
Is execjs now a requirement for Ruby on Rails applications or is there a way to exclude this gem from an installation?

Comment: OK, I can answer my own question: execjs seems to be a requirement for uglifier and coffee-script.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to install without execjs.

Comment: Comment out uglifier and coffee-script in the Gemfile if you don't want to install execjs.

Comment: Yahuda Katz posted this should be fixed in the final rails release. App in production will not require JS runtime.

Comment: @KlimentMamykin: can you provide a link for Yehuda's post?

Comment: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/14/what-the-hell-is-happening-to-rails/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you comment out all gems relating to the asset pipeline from the Gemfile then execjs will not be installed (and this should work fine in production).

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
#group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
#  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
#  gem 'uglifier'
#end
```